# How to take a portrait photo when device is in landscape

Tags: android, camera

I am making a rather specialist camera app for a device which is physically always going to be held in a landscape orientation. Part of the spec is that it must optionally be able to preview and take photos in a portrait orientation - see configuration 'A' below.
[image]

(Now before anyone votes to close this question suggesting this is a repeat of [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549561/any-problems-taking-a-portrait-photo-when-device-is-in-landscape), let me point out that the other question merely addressed *whether* it was possible or not - to which the claimed answer is yes. This question, is about *how* it can be done.)

I have already set up a TextureView for the preview and called camera.setPreviewTexture(), so I see the camera's image on screen. I also have code up and running which does the landscape version of what I require, see configuration 'B' below.

[image]
In order to set up the camera parameters, I first of all read the camera's own settings using getParameters(), then modify just the ones I want to change. So in the case of configuration 'B', it is just a matter of executing the following code:

```
camera_parameters = camera.getParameters();
camera_parameters.setPreviewSize(640,480); 
camera_parameters.setPictureSize(640,480); 
camera.setParameters(camera_parameters);
```

(**EDIT:** I already checked that 640x480 was available for both preview and picture sizes).
The app then works works exactly as I would expect.

The problem comes when attempting to get configuration 'A' working. This time, I set the texture view to be wider than it is tall, and execute the following code:

```
camera_parameters = camera.getParameters();
camera_parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
camera_parameters.setPreviewSize(640,480); 
camera_parameters.setPictureSize(640,480); 
camera.setParameters(camera_parameters);
```

Unfortunately this does not quite do the job. What I end up with when the app runs looks more like this:
[image]
As you can see the image displayed in this preview is essentially an image that is wider than it is tall, that has been deformed into a rectangle that is taller than it is wide. The resulting saved jpeg image file is also wider than it is tall.

I thought that perhaps I needed to change the code to the following:

```
camera_parameters = camera.getParameters();
camera_parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
camera_parameters.setPreviewSize(480,640); 
camera_parameters.setPictureSize(480,640); 
camera.setParameters(camera_parameters);
```

But this causes an exception "setParameters failed".

So my question is, what parameters should I be setting to what values, between `camera.getParameters();` and `setParameters(camera_parameters);` ?

Comment: +1 because your question just answered a question I had for a while on how to set the size of a photo.

Comment: There is no requirement that any device support 480x640/640x480 for either previews or pictures. Please use the appropriate methods on `Camera.Parameters` to find out what is available. Similarly, there is no requirement for any device to honor `set("orientation", "portrait")` or any other combination of strings. To preview in portrait from a device in landscape, I'd rotate the `TextureView` 90 degrees. I doubt it is possible to reliably take portrait photos while held in landscape.

Comment: FYI, I already checked, and printed out the list of available preview and pictures sizes and 640,480 was available (I will edit OP).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "rotate the TextureView 90 degrees".

Answer (score 0):

i work a lot with camera and picture to realize an application similar to "face in hole"
In this case the problem is that you try to set the size with absolute value.

```
 camera_parameters.setPreviewSize(480,640);
 camera_parameters.setPictureSize(480,640);
```

This can throw exception on your phone/emulator and in another can work well. The problem is that you must read the allowed size ( releated to the camera ) and create an algorithm to choose between them.
The functions are:

1. [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes())
2. [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes())

Here you can find a very simple example:

```
 mCamera = Camera.open();
 Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
 List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
 // See which sizes the camera supports and choose one of those
 mSize = sizes.get(0);
 params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
 mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

With this tips you can find the solution that best fit your expectation.

Comment: I already did exactly that (see the "edit" in the original question). This confirmed that 640x480 was available for both preview and picture. What I also noticed is that there *wasn't* an option for any supported sizes where the height was greater than the width. I had just assumed that this was catered for by set("orientation", "portrait"); ... perhaps not! Perhaps its impossible?